# titanium appcelerator camera not found on samsung s-series or google pixel devices

Tags: android, android-camera, appcelerator-titanium, titanium-alloy

I am developing a mobile app using Appcelerator Titanium Alloy. The code below opens the camera, allows the user to take a picture, and attaches it to an email template successfully on all iOS devices and the majority of Android devices I have been able to test with, including Motorola, LG, Panasonic, Samsung (not s-series works fine). When I attempt to open the camera on certain devices (so far only Samsung S7 & Google Pixel, but my access to devices is limited), I get an error:

**[ERROR] :  TiMedia: (KrollRuntimeThread) [12968,135705] Failed to create external storage directory.**

I see that error in Appcelerator studio, and on the device I see the pop-up message "Please run this test on a device", which means it must be returning true at the line `if (error.code == Titanium.Media.NO_CAMERA)` below.

I have already requested external storage permissions and camera permissions at this point. I can't figure out why this only occurs on certain devices, and it does not seem to be specific to a certain version of Android OS. Any help would be appreciated.

```
var takePic = Ti.UI.createButton({
        width : 127,
        height : 42,
        bottom : 50,
        left : 8,
        title : 'Take a picture',
        color : "#fff",
        backgroundColor : "#555555",
        borderColor : "#FFFFFF",
        borderRadius : "10px",
        borderWidth : "1px"

    });

takePic.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        var win = Titanium.UI.createWindow({//Open Camera

        });

        Titanium.Media.showCamera({
            success : function(event) {
                if (event.mediaType == Ti.Media.MEDIA_TYPE_PHOTO) {

                    win = Titanium.UI.currentWindow;

                    if (osName == "android") {
                        var img_view = Titanium.UI.createImageView({
                            height : '100%',
                            width : '100%',
                        });

                        win.add(img_view);
                    }
                    try {
                        picURL = event.media;
                        picRaw = event.media;
                        pictureSet = true;
                        $.videoButton.enabled = false;
                        $.videoButton.backgroundColor = "#DDDDDD";
                        $.savePic.show();
                        format = "Picture";
                    } catch(e) {
                        alert("An Error:" + e.message);
                    }

                } else {
                    var alert = createErrorAlert({
                        text : "An error occured getting the media. Please check file size and format and try again."
                    });
                    $.yesLatLon.add(alert);
                    alert.show();
                }

            },
            cancel : function() {
                //called when user cancels taking a picture

            },
            error : function(error) {
                //called when there's an error
                var a = Titanium.UI.createAlertDialog({
                    title : 'Camera'
                });
                if (error.code == Titanium.Media.NO_CAMERA) {
                    a.setMessage('Please run this test on device');
                } else {
                    a.setMessage('Unexpected error: ' + error.code);
                }
                a.show();
            },
            saveToPhotoGallery : true,
            allowEditing : false,
            autohide : true, //Important!
            mediaTypes : [Ti.Media.MEDIA_TYPE_PHOTO]
        });
        alert.hide();
    });
```

Comment: Seems like a permissions issue. Whenever you take a picture on android it is gonna try to save it in the phone. Make sure you are asking for storage permissions to use the file system AND the camera.

Comment: I've got the following permissions requested in the Tiapp.xml

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"/>`